# Combine two Python Dataframes - smaller one gets copied down

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm wanting to combine two dataframes together in Python. I already achieve this with the current code: `df1= pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)`. This produces:

```
PART NUM | DATE      | Out of Tolerance | Performance | Mean    | Std. deviation
01       | 11/08/2022| 0                | 1           | -0.9749 | 0.258943
NaN        NaN         0                | 1           | -0.9689 | 0.260066
```

`df1` = `PART NUM` and `DATE`

`df2` = `Out of Tolerance`, `Performance`, `Mean`, `Std. deviation`

My problem is that I want the contents of `PART NUM` and `DATE` to be copied down into the second row so that there are no `NaN`'s. I also don't just want to add another `df2` to the concat function like so `df1= pd.concat([df2, df2, df1], axis=1)` as its not always two rows sometimes it could be three rows, one row, or more.

Is there a dynamic way to achieve this within Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can backward fill:

```
df['PART NUM'] = df['PART NUM'].bfill()
```